# Problem #11 in Royden-Fitzpatrick $4^{th}$ edition.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

The problem is given below:

> [image]

**EDIT:(According to the hint I received from @Marios Gretsas)**

**FIRST: Proving this change of variables formula for indicator functions of sets**

Since indicator functions of sets $\chi$ are measurable (I know how to prove this) and since Measure is translation invariant by pg.30 in Royden and Fitzpatrick, then the statement is true for indicator functions of sets.

**SECOND: Considering simple functions.**

Now define a simple function $\psi$ as follows: $$\psi = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i} . \chi_{E_{i}}$$

Where each $E_{i} = \psi^{-1}(a_{i}) = \{ x \in E | \psi(x) = a_{i}\}$ and where $E_{i}$ are disjoint and $a_{i}$ are not necessarily distinct.

Now, since the integration given in the question is over the interval $[\alpha + \gamma, \beta + \gamma]$ which is of finite measure, which is the length of the interval. And by the definition of integrations for simple functions given on pg.71, we have $$\int _{[\alpha + \gamma, \beta + \gamma]} \psi = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i} . m(E_{i})$$

Now, I am stuck, what is the relation between $E_{i}'s$ and my indicator functions?

I am also starting to follow the suggestion of @amsmath

**EDIT:**

Also I have a question Do I have to do the following:

reduce from simple functions to characteristic functions of measurable sets, to char. fcns of $G_{\delta}$ sets, to char. fcns. of open sets, to char. fcns. of open intervals.

**EDIT:**

I also found this question, I feel it may be helpful. [Integration by substitution for Lebesgue integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247833/integration-by-substitution-for-lebesgue-integration)

Comment: @Mathstupid Why don't you just follow the suggestion in the exercise to start with simple functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay we know what for a simple function $\phi (x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\chi_{ E_i} $ defined such that $\bigcup E_i \subset [\alpha+\gamma , \beta+\gamma]$, we have  $$\int_{[\alpha+\gamma,\beta+\gamma]} \phi = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i m(E_i)$$. Now

$$\phi(t+\gamma) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} a_1 &, t+\gamma \in E_1 \\ a_2 &, t+\gamma \in E_2 \\ \vdots & \end{array}\right.$$ Now we can define $E'_i = E_i - \gamma $  then  $\bigcup E'_i \subset [\alpha , \beta] $.

$$\phi(t+\gamma) =\phi' (t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} a_1 &, t \in E'_1 \\ a_2 &, t \in E'_2 \\ \vdots & \end{array}\right.$$. Thus finally

$$\int_{[\alpha , \beta] }\phi(t+\gamma) =\int_{[\alpha , \beta ]} \phi' (t) = \sum a_i m(E'_i) = \sum a_i m(E_i ) = \int_{[\alpha + \gamma, \beta+\gamma]} \phi(x) dx $$.

Now we know that for bounded function $g$ defined on $E= [\alpha+\gamma ,\beta+\gamma ]$ we define the upper integral of $g$ as 
$$\inf \left\{ \int_E \psi : \psi \text{ is simple and } \psi \geq g \right\}$$

and the lower integral as $$\sup \left\{ \int_E \phi : \phi \text{ is simple and } \phi \leq g \right\} $$

And $g$ is integrable if both values are equal.

and we know from the simple approximation lemma that for a bounded function $g$ on $[\alpha+\gamma  , \beta+\gamma ]$ there exists two simple functions $\phi \leq g \leq \psi $ for any given $\epsilon$ such that $\psi - \phi < \epsilon $.

Hence given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\phi , \psi $ simple functions such that $\phi \leq g \leq \psi $ and $\psi - \phi < \frac{\epsilon}{\beta-\alpha}$ then we have $g \leq \psi $ on $[\alpha + \gamma , \beta + \gamma] $ , then $g(t+\gamma) \leq  \psi (t+ \gamma)=\psi'(t) $ on $[\alpha , \beta]$.   $$\left|\int_{[\alpha , \beta ] } g(t+\gamma) - \int_{[\alpha + \gamma, \beta + \gamma ]}  g(x) \right| \leq \left| \int_{[\alpha , \beta ]} \psi' - \int_{[\alpha + \gamma , \beta + \gamma ]} \phi \right|\leq \int_{[\beta,\alpha]} | \psi - \phi | < \epsilon $$

Comment: Does the same proof applies if we want to show that $$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} g(at + \gamma) dt = \int_{a \alpha + \gamma}^{a \beta + \gamma}$$?

Comment: How we will define $E_{i}^{'}$  in the case I mentioned in my previous comment?

Comment: The idea is we know that $E+\gamma = \{ x + \gamma : x \in E\}$, do you mean $aE+\gamma = \{ ax+\gamma : x \in E\}$. I used that fact that $m(E) = m(E+\gamma)$ the measure is translation  invariant but is it true that $m(aE+\gamma) = m(E)$ ??

Comment: Also, if I want the integration to be over $\mathbb {R}$, How the proof will differ?

Comment: I think the answer to your previous question is yes

Comment: I have a question if we have a function $h$ that is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$. and we have $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\alpha \neq 0$. Is the function $h(\alpha x + \beta )$ still integrable over $\mathbb{R}$? I guess yes and the reasoning is similar to your above reasoning ..... am I correct?

Comment: @Mathstupid if $a=0$ then it is not yes. and $m( a,b) = b-a$ but $m((at+c,bt+c )) = t(b-a)$

Comment: I think in your previous comment you mean in the second argument of your open interval $bt + c$ ... am I correct?

Comment: Is the proof similar to the proof you gave above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100377/discussion-between-ameryr-and-intuition).

Comment: @Intuition No because $m(E) \ne m(aE+b)$ as I showed that for intervals. You need to come up with another argument.

Comment: (Completely unrelated) You should put your punctuation before you close the display equation.  That way, it appears at the end of the display equation instead of beginning the next line.

Comment: I hope that you can answer the question I asked you @AmerYR I am waiting for your response.

Comment: I do not think that your definition for simple function in the first line is correct

Comment: How do you get your last integral in the last line from the one preceeding it?

Comment: @Mathstupid I forgot to write the characteristic function I fixed it

Comment: @Secretly We have $\psi'$ which is bigger than $g(t+\gamma)$ and phi which is less than $g(t)$ so the difference is bigger the other difference