# Proving proposition 23 in case of $f < 0$ on pg.92 & 93 in "Royden and Fitzpatrick".

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-integral

The proposition and the first part of its proof are given below:

> [image]

The book said "The theorem follows by establishing it separately for the positive and negative parts of $f$" but the book never did the proof for the negative part, could anyone help me establishing this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prove the result for non-negative integrable functions $f$ you can apply it to $f^{+}$ as well as $f^{-}$ because these are non-negative integrable functions. Once you do this you can use the fact that $\int_E |f| =\int_E f^{+}+\int_E f^{-}$.

Comment: Could you please (if you have time) look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3408687/problem-11-in-royden-fitzpatrick-4th-edition

Comment: @Mathstupid Integral is linear. If you know that result for indicator functins you know it for simple functions by just taking linear combinations.

Comment: What if we have $a \alpha + \gamma$ instead, will the same argument also applied?